# purrr use unnested values in map to filter data

Tags: r, purrr

I want to try and filter my data in a nested column based on a value in the unnested data.

```
require(purrr)
require(dplyr)

set.seed(314)

dat1 <- data.frame(id = 1:3, tres1 = 1:3*10, tres2 = 2:4*10)

dat2 <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 20),
                   var = rnorm(20, 20,5))

dat <- dat1 %>% inner_join(dat2 %>% nest(-id))
```

I tried this (and other possibilities)

```
dat %>%
  mutate(map(data, ~filter(var > tres1, var < tres2)))
```

I do not know how to solve this.

```
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
  $ id  : int  1 2 3
$ tres1: num  10 20 30
$ tres2: num  20 30 40
$ data:List of 3
..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  20 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ var: num  13.6 23.6 15.8 16.5 20.6 ...
..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  20 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ var: num  13.6 23.6 15.8 16.5 20.6 ...
..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  20 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ var: num  13.6 23.6 15.8 16.5 20.6 ...
```

Comment: Do you need `dat %>% mutate(new = map2(data, tres, ~ .x %>% filter(var > .y)))`

Comment: Yes! Would something similar be possible with multiple values (such as `filter(var > treslo, var < treshi)`

Comment: You meant multiple columns of thresh

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to use multiple columns, then `pmap` would be better.  Note that

```
library(tidyverse)
dat2 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   nest %>%
   inner_join(dat1) %>% 
   mutate(data = pmap(list(data, tres1, tres2), ~ 
              ..1 %>% 
                  filter(var > ..2, var < ..3)))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     id data              tres1 tres2
#  <int> <list>            <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 <tibble [10 × 1]>    10    20
#2     2 <tibble [8 × 1]>     20    30
#3     3 <tibble [0 × 1]>     30    40
```

Note: According to `?pmap`

> For a two argument function, use .x and .y
>
> For more arguments, use ..1, ..2, ..3 e

To be consistent, we have used `..` notation although the `.x` and `.y` should work for the first 2 variables here